# USBIP does not work even with modprobe vhci-hcd. ERROR open vhci_driver

Tags: networking

I am trying to pass USB over Network. I found USBIP Project but I have a problem. I have googled but the only answer I've got was modprobe vhci-hci. I have included this mod.

on my host system

```
 [xxx@archlinux ~]$ lsmod | grep vhci_hcd
vhci_hcd               49152  0
usbip_core             32768  2 vhci_hcd,usbip_host
usbcore               282624  7 usbhid,usb_storage,vhci_hcd,usbip_host,xhci_pci,uas,xhci_hcd
usb_common             16384  3 vhci_hcd,usbcore,usbip_core
```

netstat -tap gave me following:

```
    netstat -tap | grep usbip
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:triomotion      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      714/usbipd
```

on my client system:

```
[root@anarchy]: /home/owner># usbip list -r serverip
Exportable USB devices
======================
 - serverip
        1-1: SanDisk Corp. : Cruzer Blade (0781:5567)
           : /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1
           : (Defined at Interface level) (00/00/00)


[root@anarchy]: /home/owner># lsmod | grep vhci
vhci_hcd               49152  0
usbip_core             32768  2 vhci_hcd,usbip_host
usbcore               282624  7 usbhid,vhci_hcd,usbip_host,ehci_hcd,ohci_pci,ohci_hcd,ehci_pci
usb_common             16384  3 vhci_hcd,usbcore,usbip_core


[root@anarchy]: /home/owner># usbip attach -r serverip -b 1-1
libusbip: error: udev_device_get_sysattr_value failed
usbip: error: open vhci_driver
usbip: error: query
```

with --debug flag

```
usbip: debug: usbip.c:141:[run_command] running command: `attach'
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:264:[usbip_vhci_driver_open] available ports: 16
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:275:[usbip_vhci_driver_open] available controllers: 2
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:128:[refresh_imported_device_list] controller 0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:68:[parse_status] hub hs port 0 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:69:[parse_status] socket 0 lbusid 0-0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:68:[parse_status] hub hs port 1 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:69:[parse_status] socket 0 lbusid 0-0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:68:[parse_status] hub hs port 2 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:69:[parse_status] socket 0 lbusid 0-0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:68:[parse_status] hub hs port 3 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:69:[parse_status] socket 0 lbusid 0-0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:68:[parse_status] hub hs port 4 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:69:[parse_status] socket 0 lbusid 0-0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:68:[parse_status] hub hs port 5 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:69:[parse_status] socket 0 lbusid 0-0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:68:[parse_status] hub hs port 6 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:69:[parse_status] socket 0 lbusid 0-0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:68:[parse_status] hub hs port 7 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:69:[parse_status] socket 0 lbusid 0-0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:68:[parse_status] hub ss port 8 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:69:[parse_status] socket 0 lbusid 0-0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:68:[parse_status] hub ss port 9 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:69:[parse_status] socket 0 lbusid 0-0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:68:[parse_status] hub ss port 10 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:69:[parse_status] socket 0 lbusid 0-0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:68:[parse_status] hub ss port 11 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:69:[parse_status] socket 0 lbusid 0-0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:68:[parse_status] hub ss port 12 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:69:[parse_status] socket 0 lbusid 0-0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:68:[parse_status] hub ss port 13 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:69:[parse_status] socket 0 lbusid 0-0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:68:[parse_status] hub ss port 14 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:69:[parse_status] socket 0 lbusid 0-0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:68:[parse_status] hub ss port 15 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:69:[parse_status] socket 0 lbusid 0-0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:104:[parse_status] exit
libusbip: error: udev_device_get_sysattr_value failed
usbip: error: open vhci_driver
usbip: error: query
```

client system
lsmod | grep usbip

```
usbip_host             32768  0
usbip_core             32768  2 vhci_hcd,usbip_host
usbcore               282624  7 usbhid,vhci_hcd,usbip_host,ehci_hcd,ohci_pci,ohci_hcd,ehci_pci
usb_common             16384  3 vhci_hcd,usbcore,usbip_core

[root@anarchy]: /home/owner># lsmod | grep vhci_hcd
vhci_hcd               49152  0
usbip_core             32768  2 vhci_hcd,usbip_host
usbcore               282624  7 usbhid,vhci_hcd,usbip_host,ehci_hcd,ohci_pci,ohci_hcd,ehci_pci
usb_common             16384  3 vhci_hcd,usbcore,usbip_core
```

anyone a solution?

Comment: I have this problem too. I did not solve it yet. This may be relevant. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=233424